# Stopping a run/simulation in Netlogo when the system reaches 95% equilibrium

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to stop a run in Netlogo when the system reaches equilibrium? The ticks just keep running and I would like my simulation to automatically stop when a near-equilibrium change is reached, i.e. when the system is close to 95% equilibrium.

Comment: how do you measure equilibrium? What stops changing? If you have some variable that changes each run and you want to stop when it's not changing any more, then all you need to is keep track of the previous value and stop if the new value is not much different. But there are many other types of equilibrium that this won't work, and it's not clear whether you might get small changes when the system is not nearing equilibrium and this approach would stop it too early.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, for my model a near-equilibrium would also work. It is reached when all the agents in the system are not changing in terms of concentration overall.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation where I've taken two approaches.  When there is a variable for which stability indicates quasi-equilibrium, I keep a history of that variable in a list and check the standard deviation of the most recent "n" values.  If that variance falls below a given value, I stop the simulation.  For you, that might be concentration.  Of course if the variable is moving smoothly in one direction or another you might get a false positive, so as a check, I've also regressed the most recent values to see if the slope is "close" to zero.  I'd be hard put to put a percentage on closeness- that will depend on the situation.  But, something like this might do.

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: Thanks Charles, I ended up doing something similar by storing values of a variable in a list. But what I do is this: I keep calculating the mean of the sum of that list and I then check co-efficient of variance. Now, if I do this after every run, the delta or change between two consecutive runs would be too small usually and the system will stop running prematurely. So I do this after x number of iterations, could be 5 or 10. Am I making any sense? I just came up with this myself. I didn't quite understand about the regression bit that you mentioned though. Would you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are doing.  Your list of values contains the values of a single variable over time?  If that is correct, then l think that looking at the mean of the whole list will not give you what you want.  As the list grows, the addition of one more value will change the mean by less and less, even if the value is oscillating quite a bit.  I think you would be better off just looking at the variance of the most recent n values. For me, n is 10, but that is a bit arbitrary.

Comment: A regression simply computes a straight line through a series of points and gives the slope and intercept of that line.  When the variable is graphed against time, if a variable is "stable", the slope of that line should be close to zero.  The variable is neither trending up nor down over time.  NetLogo has two extensions that can be used for regression, the matrix extension and the stats extension.